# How to query for node's subtree in gremlin?

Tags: groovy, graph, titan, gremlin

Having a graph, actually it is a tree: vertexes are nodes, edges are labeled as "subnode" and directed from child to parent.

I need to make gremlin query to get recursive structure as this:

```
node_info = [properties: node.map(), 
             subnodes: [...list of node_info items...]]
```

Groovy function describes more precisely what I need to get:

```
def get_node_hierarchy(node_id) {

    def get_hierarchy(node) {
        def hierarchy_list = []

        for (subnode in node.in('subnode')) {
            sub_hierarchy = get_hierarchy(subnode)
            hierarchy_list.add(sub_hierarchy)
        }

        [properties: node.map(), subnodes: hierarchy_list]
    }

    node = g.V('node_id', node_id).next()
    get_hierarchy(node)
}

result = get_node_hierarchy(1)
```

Is it possible to implement this using a single Gremlin query?

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Tree-Pattern